# Sensing a decimal in a textBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, decimal

I'm developing a kind of calculator for the Windows Phone.

It doesn't need to use decimals. (who needs .39 of a brick)

How would I detect that there is a decimal in a string or a textBox?

EDIT: Thanks, @Bala R and @Afnan. But what I was after was something that filtered out letters as well. My answer's below.

Comment: there's a tutorial for a "numbers only" textbox here: http://www.atleyhunter.com/2010/11/12/making-textbox-numbers-only-for-windows-phone-7/

Comment: A brick-layer, obviously.  Put him out of business by using int.TryParse() instead of decimal.TryParse().

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Thanks for the link. @Hans Passant: Yes, I was already using int.TryParse(brick1, out brick2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modyfying the `Bala R` code gives

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains(".") || textBox1.Text.Contains(","))
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty);
        }
```

this will remove the invalid characters that are entered as the input is written

Comment: Wow, this is, most definitely, **the best** answer I have ever received on StackOverflow. Worked immediately. (aside from a minor xaml change)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to see if there is a "period" in string

```
 bool hasDecimal = textBox.Text.Contains(".")
```

but more than one period would be bad for a decimal value.

Comment: Note that different cultures might use different decimal symbols

Comment: As Luke said, different cultures use different symbols, you can find the appropriate symbol at CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator

Comment: @Nigel: Thanks, I would have never guessed that on my own.             @Bala: Yeah, I would expect some users to tap more than one decimal accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to check whether the value is a valid decimal value.

Use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) method:

```
decimal value;

string textValue = textBox.Text;
bool isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(textValue, out value)
```

Comment: Note that `decimal.TryParse` will happily parse integers (since they are also valid decimals). I think the OP wants to allow integer values but not (non-integer) decimals.

Comment: @ LukeH: I think that he can check the `integer.TryParse` first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found works the best:

`bool bNeedToUpdate = false;
            StringBuilder szNumbersOnly = new StringBuilder();
            TextBox textSource = sender as TextBox;
            if (null == textSource)
                return;
            foreach (char ch in textSource.Text)
            {
                if (("0123456789").Contains(ch.ToString()))
                {
                    szNumbersOnly.Append(ch);
                }
                else
                {
                    bNeedToUpdate = true;
                }
            }
            if (bNeedToUpdate)
            {
                textSource.Text = szNumbersOnly.ToString();
                textSource.SelectionStart = szNumbersOnly.Length;
            }`

I swiped this answer off Erin Fleck, a forums moderator that answered [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/8f8faa14-70e4-471f-905c-92cf95b58711) similar question.

@Afnan gets the green check because he/she/it answered my original question.